# Flutter Stripe paymentsheet is opening webpage (hooks.stripe.com) while processing payments

Tags: flutter, dart, payment, flutter-stripe

I am developing a flutter application which uses stripe for payments. I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe for this.

Everything is working fine but whenever I initiate payments I always get a webpage middleware (Screenshots attached). What am I doing wrong?[image: Stripe payment sheet and web middle ware :][image]

Here is my implementation in Flutter

```
    Future<void> makePayment(String planName, String type) async { 
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "initiating Payments, Please wait.");
   ApiProvider provider = ApiProvider();
    final tokenResponse = await provider
    .getPaymentToken(PlanPayment(planName: planName, type: type));
    if (tokenResponse != null) {`
    var _service = locator<NavigationService>();
    String secret = tokenResponse.clientSecret;

  // make a get call from this url
  Map<String, dynamic> paymentIntentData = Map();
  await payment.Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: payment.SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    merchantCountryCode: 'IN',
    testEnv: true,
    paymentIntentClientSecret: secret,
    googlePay: true,
  ));
  try {
    // await Stripe.instance.handleCardAction(secret);
    await payment.Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) {});
    await payment.Stripe.instance
        .confirmPaymentSheetPayment()
        .then((value) async {
      // await _service.pushNamed(paymentStatus, args: {'isSuccess': true});
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // await _service.pushNamed(paymentStatus, args: {'isSuccess': false});

    print("Stripe error" + e.toString());
  }

  await provider
      .confirmPayment(tokenResponse.transactionId)
      .then((value) async {
    await _service
        .pushReplacementNamed(paymentStatus, args: {"isSuccess": value});
  });
}
```

}

`

Comment: Hello, did you get any solution for this? I also ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a webhook put in your account?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

```
        1)Provide valid Secret key 
        2)Provide valid Publisable key
        3)Update flutterstripe pacakge
        4)provide valid currency code to create stripe account country  
           ex :- stripe account create india to inr etc..
        
        
        5)Right Way to implemet
        
         - Main.dart to main method run app to implemet
        
               ex :--
                  Stripe.publishableKey = "your publishable key ";
        
         - create controller / method
        
        
        code:-
          Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntentData;
        
        Future<void> makePayment({amount}) async {
            try {
              paymentIntentData =
                  await createPaymentIntent(amount: amount, currency: 'INR');
              if (paymentIntentData != null) {
                await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
                    paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
                  // applePay: true,
                  googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(merchantCountryCode: 'INR'),
                  merchantDisplayName: "PGA",
                  customerId: paymentIntentData!['customer'],
                  paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
                  customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentData!['ephemeralkey'],
                ));
              }
        
              displayPaymentSheet();
            } catch (err) {
              logger.e(err);
            }
           
          }
        
          void displayPaymentSheet() async {
            try {
              await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
              Get.snackbar("PaymentInfo", "Payment Successfully");
            } on Exception catch (e) {
              if (e is StripeException) {
                logger.e(e, "Error From Stripe");
              } else {
                logger.e(e, "Unforeseen error");
              }
            } catch (e) {
              logger.e("exeption === $e");
            }
           
          }
        
          var id = "";
          createPaymentIntent({amount, currency}) async {
            try {
              Map<String, dynamic> body = {
                'amount': calculateAmount(amount: amount),
                'currency': currency,
                'payment_method_types[]': 'card'
              };
              var response = await http.post(
                Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
                headers: {
                  'Authorization':
                      'Bearer YourSecretKey',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: body,
              );
              if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                var decode = jsonDecode(response.body);
                logger.e(decode);
        
                id = decode['id'];
                return decode;
              }
            } catch (e) {
              logger.e(e, "error charging user");
            }
           
          }
        
          calculateAmount({amount}) {
            logger.e(amount.round());
            final a = (int.parse(amount.toString())) * 100;
            logger.e(a.toString());
            update();
            return a.toString();
          }
        
        
 6)      How to  Access  Stripe payment :-
ex :- any button click 
        
          ontap : (){
    makePayment(
      amount: "200")
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).